# What is flutter "web server"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Beside `chrome` flutter has `web server` build type, What is it and if it's like chrome, whats their difference?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome launches the application using the development compiler in a Chrome browser.

A release (web server) build uses dart2js (instead of the development compiler) to produce a single JavaScript file main.dart.js. You can create a release build using release mode (flutter run --release) or by using flutter build web. This populates a build/web directory with built files, including an assets directory, which need to be served together.

From the manual https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web